# SQL Join two Tables and Insert/ Remove depending on existing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I am a newbie to SQL and seek help. I have two Table structures as below:

Table: `T_Schools`

```
ID      |   SchoolID        |  ChildID
--------+-------------------+-----------
1       |   School1         |  Child1
2       |   School2         |  Child2
3       |   School3         |  Child3
4       |   School4         |  Child4
7       |   School5         |  Child5
8       |   School6         |  Child6
9       |   School7         |  NULL
5       |   School8         |  NULL
6       |   School9         |  NULL
10      |   School10        |  Child10
```

Table: `T_Children`

```
ChildID | ChildName 
--------+--------------
Child1  |   
Child2  |
Child3  |
Child4  |
Child5  |
Child6  |
Child7  |
Child8  |
Child9  |
Child10 |
```

I have two scenarios:

**Scenario #1**: Child Addition

If a new `ChildID` is added in the `T_children` table and a corresponding value is not present in `T_Schools`, then those `ChildID`'s need to be added into the first available `SchoolID`.

Expected Result: `T_Schools`

```
9       |   School7         |  Child7
5       |   School8         |  Child8
6       |   School9         |  Child9
```

**Scenario #2**: Child Removal

If a `ChildID` is removed from the `T_children` table, then the corresponding `ChildID`'s from `T_Schools` should be made NULL and those `SchoolID`'s should be made available for adding new `ChildID`'s.

For example: if `ChildID = Child3` is removed from `T_Children`, then `T_Schools` should be like this:

```
3       |   School3         |  NULL
```

For scenario #1, I tried the query shown here, but it does not seem to return the required result:

```
UPDATE M
SET M.ChildID = N.ChildID
FROM T_Schools M 
LEFT JOIN T_Children N ON M.ChildID <> N.ChildID  
WHERE M.ChildID IS NULL
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So each `School` is only allowed a single `Child`?

Comment: @Charlieface : yes as per the requirement: each schoolID will have a single childID, unless that childID from the T_Children is removed, then corresponding childID in T_Schools will be made NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like for inserting, you just need to grab the first available `School` row.

So given two parameters `@ChildID` and `@ChildName`:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT T_Children (ChildID, ChildName)
VALUES (@ChildID, @ChildName);

UPDATE TOP (1) T_Schools
SET ChildID = @ChildID
WHERE ChildID IS NULL;

COMMIT;
```

And for deletion, do the same in reverse

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE T_Schools
SET ChildID = NULL
WHERE ChildID = @ChildID;

DELETE T_Children
WHERE ChildID = @ChildID;

COMMIT;
```

---

You can also do this using a Table Valued Parameter. For example, if you had a TVP containing the columns `ChildID, ChildName` you can do the following:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT T_Children (ChildID, ChildName)
SELECT t.ChildID, t.ChildName
FROM @tvp t;

UPDATE s
SET ChildID = t.ChildID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM T_Schools
    WHERE ChildID IS NULL
) s
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM @tvp
) t ON t.rn = s.rn;

COMMIT;
```

And for deletion:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE s
SET ChildID = NULL
FROM T_Schools s
JOIN @tvp t ON t.ChildID = s.ChildID;

DELETE c
FROM c T_Children
JOIN @tvp t ON t.ChildID = c.ChildID;

COMMIT;
```

---

One final option, although I advise to avoid it if possible, is to use a trigger, and rely on cascading foreign key for the delete:

```sql
ALTER TABLE T_Schools
  ADD CONSTRAINT SchoolChild
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES T_Children (ChildID);
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSchool ON T_Children
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

UPDATE s
SET ChildID = t.ChildID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM T_Schools
    WHERE ChildID IS NULL
) s
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM inserted
) t ON t.rn = s.rn;
```

Comment: Thank you for the proportion, however the insertion and removal of ChildID will not occur for a single ChildID, hence using childID param will not effective. ChildID's may be inserted / removed multiple at a time. Hence need a generic solution

Comment: See latest edits

Comment: Thank you so much - it works like a charm, now I can sleep peace. :)
The table Value param with RowNumber did the trick.

Comment: just to add, I added the OrderBy along with the ID column, so that the addition happens in a sequential order :)